# DeltaTable.create fails with Minio identifier due to syntax error

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, delta-lake, minio

Take this code:
[image: Java code]

Here's the output:

```
boolean is false
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
Syntax error at or near ':'(line 1, pos 3)

== SQL ==
s3a://spark-test/delta-table-three
---^^^
```

Why is the identifier fine when checking if it exists, but gives syntax error when using to create a table?  BTW, if I check if a known table exists, it returns true as expected.  So the isDeltaTable works just fine with the identifier.

*Note: I'm using Minio as my storage and not AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you use `tableName` it should be registered table name, like, in Hive Metastore ([doc](https://docs.delta.io/latest/api/python/index.html#delta.tables.DeltaTableBuilder.tableName)).  In your case you provide a path to a bucket, so you need to use the `location` function instead ([doc](https://docs.delta.io/latest/api/python/index.html#delta.tables.DeltaTableBuilder.location)), as it's shown in the [docs](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-batch.html#create-a-table):

```py
DeltaTable.createOrReplace(spark) \
  .addColumn("...", "INT") \
  .location("s3a://bucket/path") \
  .execute()
```

Comment: Alex, thank you so much for taking the time to respond. That fixed it.